# Node.js Azure File Service - 403 Error Debugging

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-storage-files

I'm currently experiencing a 403 error when attempting to use Azure's Node.js SDK. The function below works perfectly when I call it directly:

```
module.exports = function (file, callback) {
  if (!fs.existsSync('./data')) {
    mkdirp('./data', function (err) {
      if (err) console.log(err)
    })
  }
  fileService.getFileToStream('chatbot', '', file, fs.createWriteStream('data/' + file), function (err, res, response) {
    if (!err) {
      fs.readFile('data/' + file, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
        if (!err) {
          callback(null, data)
        } else {
          callback(err)
        }
      })
    } else {
      callback(err)
    }
  })
}
```

However, when I call this from my wider application then I receive a 403 error:

```
{ StorageError: Forbidden
    at Function.StorageServiceClient._normalizeError (/Users/tombarton/Sites/TestApplication/node_modules/azure-storage/lib/common/services/storageserviceclient.js:1174:23)
    at FileService.StorageServiceClient._processResponse (/Users/tombarton/Sites/TestApplication/node_modules/azure-storage/lib/common/services/storageserviceclient.js:729:50)
    at Request.processResponseCallback [as _callback] (/Users/tombarton/Sites/TestApplication/node_modules/azure-storage/lib/common/services/storageserviceclient.js:310:37)
    at Request.self.callback (/Users/tombarton/Sites/TestApplication/node_modules/azure-storage/node_modules/request/request.js:187:22)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/Users/tombarton/Sites/TestApplication/node_modules/azure-storage/node_modules/request/request.js:1044:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/Users/tombarton/Sites/TestApplication/node_modules/azure-storage/node_modules/request/request.js:965:12)
  name: 'StorageError',
  message: 'Forbidden',
  code: 'Forbidden',
  statusCode: 403,
  requestId: '51ce6605-001a-00c1-1d52-ae966b000000' }
```

The problem is that I can't seem to debug this any further than a 403 error. As the code works perfectly independently then I know the access keys aren't a problem. Azure Storage allows you to log access data for Tables, Blobs and Queues, but not for File Service, which seems incredibly frustrating (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/enabling-storage-logging-and-accessing-log-data#HowtoenableStorageLoggingusingtheWindowsAzureManagementPortal).

Has anyone got any ideas regarding how I could debug this further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an [issue in the ApplicationInsights package](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-node.js/issues/143) that causes 403 responses from storage. This issue was fixed in version 0.18.0.

Comment: Thank you! I'm on the latest version on ApplicationInsights (0.19) but when I commented out everything to do with ApplicationInsights, the application worked perfectly. I'll take a look and maybe raise an issue on the ApplicationInsights repo.

Answer (score 2):

You could put a debug proxy like [mitmproxy](https://mitmproxy.org/) or [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or [Charles](https://www.charlesproxy.com/) in between to see the difference between requests and responses.

```
NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0 HTTP_PROXY=http://127.0.0.1:8888 node app.js
```